# How to get the number of lanes in a road from OSM data

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

I have OSM data stored in my Postgresql server. I want to get the number of lanes present in a road.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: You are aware of the [lanes key](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:lanes)?